# Inserting a value from a drop down list to UserProfile Table while registering a user

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on an Asp.Net MVC application in which I am using the default "`Register`" page to insert a new user into default `UserProfile` table which has `Id,UserName and Password` fields. But, as per my requirement I have added one more field to it named `CompanyId` which references to a `Company name` in a different table.
To insert `CompanyId` into UserProfile table I am using a drop down list in register page which has a list of `company names` but I am not sure how to insert Id when I register a user.

I am using following HTML for list of companies in register.cshtml

```
 <li>
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyId)
      <select data-bind="options: $root.counterpartyNames, optionsText: 'CounterPartyName',        optionsValue: 'Id', value: selectedBidCounterParty, optionsCaption: 'Company'">
       </select>
 </li>
```

I am not sure how to reference the value in `Drop Down list` to insert into `UserProfile` from default `Register ActionResult` which is as follows

```
[HttpPost]
        //[AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);

                    //  WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

**Is there a better way I could do this ?**

Comment: Is ```Id``` autoincrement field ?

Comment: yes, it is an auto increment field and primary key

Comment: So it generates automatically in database when you create user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a third, optional, parameter to `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount` that allows you to pass additional user data. Just change your code to:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { CompanyId = model.CompanyId });
```

Of course, you'll also need to fix your HTML `select` element so it actually has a name to hold the posted value before you'll get anything:

```
<select name="CompanyId" ...>
```

Better would be to use a Razor helper so that the right name attribute is generated automatically:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyId, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { data_bind = "... knockout stuff ..." })
```